# Update extension UI after a Git commit in VS Code

Tags: git, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I have a VS Code extension called [Git Mob VS Code](https://github.com/rkotze/git-mob-vs-code).

I'd like to be able to call a CLI command after a commit and update my extension UI. The CLI command is easy and can be done using a `post-commit` hook. However, the issue is with updating the UI, as it has no way of knowing if a commit has happened.

I'm looking for ideas on how I can achieve this.

Here is the related issue: [Add option to clear co-authors after commit](https://github.com/rkotze/git-mob-vs-code/issues/43)

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

One approach I have found which is *similar* to how the vs code [git extension](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/f74e473238aca7b79c08be761d99a0232838ca4c/extensions/git/src/watch.ts#L15) does it. Is to watch the `.git/COMMIT_EDITMSG` file.

When the file is updated we know a commit in progress and you can run a VS code UI update you need.

However, it's **not perfect** because if the commit fails (e.g. `commit-msg` hook exits non-zero) the file watch will still see a change and run your commands. Depending on the operations you want to do this might or might not be a big issue.

NodeJS example:

```js
const fs = require("fs");

fs.watch('project-folder/.git/COMMIT_EDITMSG', function (evt, filename) {
  if (filename) {
 // changes trigger multiple times which you might want to handle
    if (debounceFsWatch()) return;
 // run your commands here
    console.log('event, filename', evt + ' ' + filename);
  }
});
```

[Implementation in Git Mob VS Code](https://github.com/rkotze/git-mob-vs-code/blob/d3688dffb6bcff3c10b6662a4eb64c55d41d82ee/src/git/watch-for-commit.js)